# azure devops | release | script from repo to use in release

Tags: azure-devops

Helllo , I have script in repo and I want to use hem in release.
which variables should I choose to locate the path of the repo ?
is System.DefaultWorkingDirectory   ?

Answer (score 0):

If the Source alias is testalias, the final Path is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testalias`.

You can run a simple powershell task to confirm the fies.

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

dir

cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(release.primaryartifactsourcealias)

dir
```

[image]

[image]

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic for more info.